# Sometimes my ap crash when retrieve data with retrofit : D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM?

Tags: android, retrofit

this is my Retrofit retrieve code :

the error came from this line ==>> val respon = response.body()!!

( java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xfath.hormart.fragments.homechildfragments.ChildHomeFragment$getProducts$1.onResponse(ChildHomeFragment.kt:124 )

```
class ChildHomeFragment : Fragment(){
private lateinit var s: SharedPreference
private var listImageSliderHomes: ArrayList<ImageSliderHome> = ArrayList()
private var listProducts: ArrayList<Products> = ArrayList()

private lateinit var sliderView: SliderView
private lateinit var rvProductBaru: RecyclerView
private lateinit var rvElektronik: RecyclerView
private lateinit var rvPribadi: RecyclerView
private lateinit var ivNotif: ImageButton
private lateinit var uidhome: TextView
private lateinit var svhome: NestedScrollView
private lateinit var mSearchView: SearchView
private lateinit var mSwipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    getSlideImage()
}

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child_home, container, false)

    init(view)
    getProducts()
    swipeRefresh()

    s = SharedPreference(activity!!)


    return view
}

private fun getProducts() {
    ApiConfig.instanceRetrofit.getproduct().enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseModel> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseModel>, response: Response<ResponseModel>) {
            val respon = response.body()!!
            if (respon.success == 1) {
                listProducts = respon.products
                displayProduct()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseModel>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Error:" + t.message)
        }
    })
}

private fun displayProduct() {

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL

    rvProductBaru.adapter = ProductAdapter(listProducts)
    rvProductBaru.layoutManager = layoutManager

}
```

}

thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is meant that the `response.body()` returns null.
You should always do null checking for it or you can use `let` to avoid NPE.

PS: Avoid using `!!` in kotlin as it may throw NPE when the variable is null.

```
response.body()?.let { respon -> 
    if (respon.success == 1) {
       listProducts = respon.products
       displayProduct()
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot access 'body': it is private in 'Response'

Comment: i already have ==>>> implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'

Comment: what is meant by ```private in Response```? and also I would suggest you use Coroutines for retrofit if you are using kotlin

Comment: check this image : https://pasteboard.co/JNuCmfj.png

Comment: can check what is your ```response``` data-type? Is it  ```[Gradle: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0] retrofit2 public final class Response<T> extends Object```  ?

Comment: response.body()?   ------>>> if this.. the code is works.. you miss the ()

Comment: oh ya! sorry for that, I was typing it manually in here, wasnt notice the error I made. Should be using ```response.body()```

Comment: If my answer helps please upvote it. Thanks! :)